# How to pass items to bash for loop on multiple lines?

Tags: bash

I can do this in bash:

```
for n in a b c d e ; do
  echo $n
done
```

If `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` turn out to be long lines, without using a separate variable, how do I put them each on a separate line in the `for` loop syntax?

Answer (score 3):

Split the line with `\`:

```
$ for i in a \
> b \
> c \
> d ; do echo $i ; done
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a "[here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)":

```
while read n; do
  echo $n
done <<EOF                                                                                                              
some detailed stuff here                                                                                                
other things on the next line, blah blah blah
EOF
```

Of course in this particular example you can replace the entire `while` loop with `cat` but I suppose your real code is more involved.

Answer (score 0):

you can put `a b c d e` in a file and run a loop over that file.

```
while read line
do
    echo "$line \n"
done < file
```